# Should the exponent be larger than or equal 2^52 for the 64 bit floating point to be an integer irrespective of the value of the mantissa

Tags: binary, floating-point, ieee-754

I'm trying to understand if the exponent should be larger than 2^52 for the 64 bit floating point to always get integer. It seems so to me. Here is my reasoning:

If mantissa has 52 bits, then the number stored is the following:

```
1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

then we need to move the floating point to the right 52 places to get an integer. If we move it less number of places, for example, 51, then we can end up with a fractional part. For example, for the number

```
1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 x 2^51
```

it will be

```
2251799813685248.5
```

It seems that to get an integer we need to move the floating point by the number of places depending where the last value `1` is found. For example, if it's in the 30<sup>th</sup> bit, then we need to have an exponent equal to 30 (2<sup>30</sup>).

Is my logic correct?

Comment: I think the answer is basically "yes", but I'd find the question clearer if "to always get an integer" were replaced with "to be an integer irrespective of the value of the mantissa".

Comment: And, I think, "larger than 52" should be "larger than or equal to 52".

Comment: @NPE, thanks, is also my thinking starting with `It seems that to get an integer we ne...` correct?

Comment: I believe it is. The intuition, correctly, is that you need to push all the 1s out of the factional part.

Comment: @NPE, great, thanks a lot for you help! GL

Comment: @NPE, can you please take a look at [my this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304010/are-all-integers-with-exponent-over-52-are-even-in-64-bit-floating-point) related to this topic?