# Are all integers with exponent over 52 are even in 64 bit floating point

Tags: binary, ieee-754

Am I correct to conclude that:

- all integers with exponent over 52 in the 64 bit floating point will be even? For example, if exponent is `53`, and the mantissa is `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`, then the number is `100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010` - ends in `10`. If the mantissa is `54` the number ends with `100`.
- the more we increase the exponent, the more integer numbers can not be represented - for the exponent of `54` - it's impossible to represent one number - `9007199254740993`, with exponent of `55` - we can't represent `3` numbers (because we have two bits left out of mantissa which can have combinations of 01,10,11).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> all integers with exponent over 52 in the 64 bit floating point will
>   be even?

Yes. F64 has 52 encoded mantissa bits, plus an implied one. We are talking about an 'unbiased' exponent, so your value is `2^exp*1.mant`.

Imagine that to convert the F64 to an integer, the mantissa will be left-shifted by the unbiased exponent. Shifting by 52 will guarantee an integer that doesn't need rounding. 53 will guarantee an even number as zeroes are shifted in like you showed.

> the more we increase the exponent, the more integer numbers can not be
>   represented

Yes, but this goes much faster than you describe. Your example value is simply this first occurrence. In the range (2^53, 2^54) where only even numbers can be represented like you stated, only half of all integers exist in the F64, so in that range all 2^52 odd integers are unrepresented.

Comment: thanks, what do you mean by _We are talking about an 'unbiased' exponent, so your value is 2^exp*1.mant._?

Comment: I mean the actual power of two that you use for representing the value. The potential confusion is that e.g. F64 uses an 11 bit exponent field with a bias of 1023, which is added to the exponent. To represent 1.0 (exponent zero: 2^0*1.0), you end up with 1023==0x3FF, which I would often refer to as 'the exponent'. Does that help?